# How to filter eloquent results and keep some specific columns (with relationships)

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this eloquent query:

```
Person::with('mother','father')->find(1);
```

Which output this result:

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "John",
        mother_id: "4",
        father_id: "5"
        mother: {
            id: "4",
            name: "Sarah"
            mother_id: "10",
            father_id: "20"
        },
        father: {
            id: "5",
            name: "Tony",
            mother_id: "21",
            father_id: "32"
        }
    }
]
```

But I want to get something like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "John",
        mother: "Sarah",
        father: "Tony"
    }
]
```

Which is the best way to achieve this using Array and Collection methods? And if there is a way to achieve this with just Eloquent this would be better.

Comment: You could create a getNames (or something like that) accessor on the Person model that would return just the names. Using eager loading as you are, I believe three queries would be executed either way.

Comment: Maybe this could be a posibility but then, how can I "plain" the results to make it an array with one dimension?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on a recent project, adapted below:

```
$person = Person::with('mother','father')->find(1);
$arrPerson = $person->toArray();
$arrPerson['mother'] = $person->mother->name;
$arrPerson['father'] = $person->father->name;
```

If you only wanted those as indicated you could extend this to clean out the other elements.